# Mongoid Moped query not returning the same as the MongoDB shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3, moped

Creating a query using Mongoid 3.1.5 and MongoDB 2.4.9 I get different results from the Mongoid/Moped query that I do from the equivalent MongoDB query.

**Update added Mongoid query**
The query in its long for is:

```
return Video.order_by(release_date: :desc, avg_rating: :desc, title: :asc)
.where( :viewable => true, :release_date.lte => start_at_date, :release_date.gte =>
start_date, :categories.in => genre_filters).any_of({:avg_rating.gt => 1},
{:avg_rating => nil}).skip(skip*POSTERS_PER_ROW).limit(limit*POSTERS_PER_ROW)
.only(:_id, :poster_large_thumb, :title, :similar_as_string, :release_date, :avg_rating)
```

This query works correctly for everything I've thrown at it except when `genre_filters` causes only one object to be found afaik.

I get the following console output describing the Moped query:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=guide_development collection=videos 
selector={"$query"=>{"viewable"=>true, "release_date"=>{"$lte"=>2014-03-27 00:00:00 UTC,
"$gte"=>1850-01-01 00:00:00 UTC}, "categories"=>{"$in"=>["Netflix"]}, 
"$or"=>[{"avg_rating"=>{"$gt"=>1}}, {"avg_rating"=>nil}]}, "$orderby"=>
{"release_date"=>-1, "avg_rating"=>-1, "title"=>1}} 
flags=[:slave_ok] limit=60 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields={"_id"=>1,
"poster_large_thumb"=>1, "title"=>1, "similar_as_string"=>1, "release_date"=>1,
"avg_rating"=>1} (198.0939ms)
```

This returns no results--not what I expected.

After some time I came up with the following MongoDB shell query, which should be equivalent:

```
var start = new Date(2014, 3, 27);
var end - new Date(1850,1,1);

db.videos.find({
    viewable: true, release_date: {
    $lte: start, $gte: end
    }, 
    categories:{
        $in: ["Netflix"]
    }, $or: [ {avg_rating: {$gt: 1}}, {avg_rating: {$exists: false}}],
},{
    _id: 1,
    poster_large_thumb: 1,
    title: 1,
    similar_as_string: 1,
    release_date: 1,
    average_rating: 1
}).sort({release_date: -1, avg_rating: -1, title:1}).skip(0).limit(60).count()
```

Gives one result in the MongoDB shell, and this is the one object it should find.

Any ideas? Does a result of one object cause a problem in Mongoid?

Comment: Would you please supply the example document?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a difference between:

```
avg_rating: {$exists: false}
```

which means return results where the field doesn't exist

and

```
{"avg_rating"=>nil}
```

which limits to results where the field exists but is set to nil.

See the docs here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

> When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the
>   field, including documents where the field value is null. **If 
>   is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the
>   field.**

Comment: OK, what would a moped {"avg_rating"=>nil} equivalent be in the shell? I'm just trying to figure out why the query, originally written in Ruby, does not work. If I add another category to Netflix, say "Horror" in Mongoid, the same Moped query is created with one more category and all the queries work returning a bunch of docs. The only weird thing seems to be the fact that only one doc has Netflix or that there is only one category in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Beside [the difference between existence and is `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22677025/479863), you could have a time zone problem.

Rails and Mongoid will convert your timestamps to UTC for you, you can see this in the Moped log:

```
"release_date"=>{"$lte"=>2014-03-27 00:00:00 UTC, "$gte"=>1850-01-01 00:00:00 UTC}
```

Mongoid is using 2014-03-27T00:00:00Z and 1850-01-01T00:00:00Z as your timestamps so you have 00:00:00 (UTC) as the time components. The timestamps inside MongoDB will also be in UTC.

However, the MongoDB shell will use whatever time zone is currently in effect when it converts `2014-03-27` to a timestamp:

```
> new Date(2014, 3, 27)
ISODate("2014-04-27T07:00:00Z")
```

Note the 07:00:00Z. Those seven hours come from my PDT timezone (GMT-0700). You should be using the `ISODate` convenience function in the MongoDB shell thusly:

```
> ISODate('2014-03-27')
ISODate("2014-03-27T00:00:00Z")
> ISODate('1850-01-01')
ISODate("1850-01-01T00:00:00Z")
```

to make sure you get the right time zone.

Also, since you're only looking at a count, you can leave out the second argument to `find` in the MongoDB shell to simplify things. Or use `{ _id: true }` and drop the `count()` to cut down on the clutter.

Fix the problems that [tirdadc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102766/tirdadc) and I have pointed out and see if you get the same results in both cases. If you don't, then start building both queries piece by piece until they produce different results and you'll know where the problem lies. Don't forget to include the sorting options from the start and compare the returned documents IDs rather than just the counts.

Comment: The entire scenario is running on my dev machine so timezones are not the issue, I believe. Optimizing the query is appreciated but not the question. I may not have the optimal query but why do I get a result from one and on the same machine with the same DB get nothing with the other.

Comment: Don't believe, verify. What does `new Date(2014, 3, 27)` say in the MongoDB shell? Does switching to `ISODate` change anything?

Comment: I have other order_by queries to sort in ways that do not use the release date and they give the same result, no data returned. I just started with the release date sort order so now have to stick with it. For instance there is a sort by title query that specifies no date range, it returns 0 when categories = ["Netflix"] and a bunch when categories = ["Horror", "Netflix"]. Since the single Netflix movie is a horror movie, it is returned in any query that specifies categories = ["Horror", "Netflix"]

Comment: I tried a bunch of batchSize values, notice the Moped says batchSize = nil. But none had any affect on results. The shell query always works, the Mongoid never works.

Comment: Are you sure Mongoid and the MongoDB shell are talking to the same database?